# Как отслеживать местоположение в меню телеграмм бота?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

1. Как удобнее хранить иерархию меню телеграмм бота?
2. Как отслеживать какая кнопка при этом нажата?
3. У инлайн клавиатуры есть параметр келбек, и да по нему можно понять
   что за кнопка нажата, но у обычных кнопок такого параметра нету, и
   по названию текста в пункте ловить событие как то коряво...
4. Может мне реализация плохая попалась?

Comment: Удалось ли вам найти оптимальное решение? Можете поделиться?:)